# Text input with placeholder staying when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to have a text input with a "model" as placeholder let say for an telephone number.

So the text input prompts a model like

```
____/______
```

but when the users starts typing, the place holder stays like this

```
0124/5_____
```

and only underscores could be replaced.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These inputs are called 'masked inputs'. Here is a jQuery plugin: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput ([demo](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Masking, [link 1](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) or [link 2](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

like `$(this).mask("99.999.999.9-999.999");`